# How to print Talend Job Description and other details like job creation date?

Tags: talend

like jobName variable ,what is the variable for jobDescription , along with jobName I want to print job Description and job Creation date, please see attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Job metadata like description, author, creation date are not added to the generated java code, and so it is not possible to retrieve them from the job. They are only stored in source code.  You can however print project name, jobname and version, using these variables:
job name: `jobName`
job version: `jobVersion`
project: `projectName`